# API returns delete vote count for questions, but not for answers

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, answers, voting

The `questions` method of the API returns the number of delete votes among other kinds of votes: [sample query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=416226&filter=!8Ih-GPC*W--yUVGb6ErRt&site=math&run=true).

But the [answers](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids) method does not have a `delete_vote_count` field available in the filter:

[image: filter]

This could conceivably be a design decision, but is more likely an oversight.

Comment: "Delete votes" on answers are a very different beasty. They don't work the same as for questions and, IIRC, they are only available for 20K users and moderators -- and only if the A has a negative score, for the former group.