# Answer delete votes in the post sidebar

Tags: script

### About

Users with more than 1000 reputation points can see delete votes in the post timeline, but it's much more convenient to have this information fetched and added to the sidebar:

[image]

<sub>Note that the script does nothing for users under 1000 reputation points</sub>

#### How it works

- It fetches the timeline for all posts with a score lower than 0 and compares delete votes with delete events.
- It works in the review queues but makes an exception for a score lower than 1, instead of 0, for the "Low quality posts" queue. This applies to all posts, not just the one under review.
- To avoid rate limits, it makes no more than 5 concurrent fetches.

It fetches the timelines, because the delete votes are not available at the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), see [API returns delete vote count for questions, but not for answers](https://stackapps.com/questions/6206/api-returns-delete-vote-count-for-questions-but-not-for-answers).

#### Sites

Across the Stack Exchange network.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager in any major browser.
Tested with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) using [Opera](https://www.opera.com/).

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackRetrieveAnswerDeleteVotes) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackRetrieveAnswerDeleteVotes/StackRetrieveAnswerDeleteVotes.user.js)

### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.

Comment: did you test with Chrome then?

Comment: @NoviceMindset [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser)) is a "Chromium-based browser", so I didn't think it was necessary to test it. Have you had issues with it?

Comment: Does this script works in review queues? I have noticed that it does not work in review queues.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour It does now :)